# I have written this code and not getting me the output can anyone help me to sort out this?

Tags: c

```
#include<stdio.h>

int main()
{

    int num1 , num2 , result ;
    char c ;
    printf("Enter the numbers and operation \n");
    scanf("%d%d",&num1 , &num2);
    printf("Enter the sign :\n");
    scanf("%c" , c);

    if(c == '+')
    {
        result = num1 + num2 ;
        printf("%d \n",result);
    }
    else if (c == '-')
    {
        result = num1 - num2 ;
        printf("%d \n",result);
    }
    else if(c == '*')
    {
        result = num1 * num2 ;
        printf("%d \n",result);
    }
    else if (c == '/')
    {
        result = num1 / num2 ;
        printf("%d \n",result);
    }
    else if (c == '%')
    {
        result = num1 % num2 ;
        printf("%d \n",result);
    }
    else
    {
        printf("Error \n");
    }
    getchar();

}
```

Comment: What output do you get, and what output do you expect ?

Comment: `scanf("%c" , c);` --> `scanf(" %c" ,&c);`

Comment: @achal  is right, detailed explenation [here](https://www.codesdope.com/discussion/why-are-you-using-a-space-before-c-in-scanf-c-ch/)

Comment: Dereferencing mysterious memory area is undefined behavior.
The "output" OP receives is probably colorful.

Comment: You should start using a debugger to step through your code. This won't necessarily bring a solution but you should easily see where the problem is.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that when you are hiting the "Enter" key when you give your numbers, that char `'\r'` is stored in your char `c` raising the `else` statment.

There are two solution not to store that `\r` char

Solution 1:

```
printf("Enter the numbers and operation \n");
scanf("%d%d%*c",&num1 , &num2); // %*c skips a character to write
printf("Enter the sign :\n");
scanf("%c" , &c); //&c to store scanf in your char c

if(...)
```

Solution 2:

```
printf("Enter the numbers and operation \n");
scanf("%d%d",&num1 , &num2); 
printf("Enter the sign :\n");
scanf(" %c" , &c); // the space tells scanf to discard any of the whitespaces

if(...)
```

Comment: White space (such as blanks, tabs, or newlines) in the format string match any amount of white space, including none, in the input.

Comment: printf-family functions are always full of surprises eh?

Comment: Is that what %*c does in the end ? Sure they are haha

Comment: The `*` in scanf means that the variable is read, but not written to the instance provided.